# JWT token cannot be verified with the same secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have two different API routes, with several endpoints embedded in them. One of them is protected and is only accessible if you send a JWT token in the request. The other one, of course, is for Auth that allows a user to generate a token and then append it to every request. Assuming the relevant imports and that my **Auth** code is in `Auth.js`and that the Add **Candidate** is in `Candidate.js`:

**`Auth.js`**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let { email, password } = req.body;

    db.collection('users').findOne({ email: email }, { projection: { email: 1, password: 1, accessGranted: 1 } }, (err, userData) => {
        console.log(userData);
        if (!err) {
            let passwordCheck = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userData.password);
            if (passwordCheck) {

                if (userData.accessGranted) {

                    const payload = {
                        email: userData.email,
                        id: userData._id
                    }

                    let token = jwt.sign(payload, tokenSecret);

                    res.status(200)
                        .send({ token, email: userData.email });
                } else {
                   //.. Other Code

                }

            } else {
                // Other code
            }
        } else {
            // Other code
        }
    })
})
```

Now, I have added a middleware in the other file as such:

**`Candidate.js`**

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.body.token;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret, function (err, decoded) {
            if (!err) {
                req.decoded = decoded; 
                next();
            } else {
                // Other Code
            }
        })
    } else {
        // Other Code
    }
}
```

);

**Error:** `jwt` complains that the token I have supplied is invalid.

For prototyping, I have saved the token in a JS `const` variable and I have double-checked that the `tokenSecret` in both the files is the same. What's wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error when running `jwt.verify`?

Comment: Yes. It says I am supplying an invalid token.

Comment: does the token look correct when you `console.log(req.body.token)` ? perhaps the issue is with the token being sent

Comment: Yep. Same as how it looked when I sent it from my browser.

Comment: and what is this `jwt.` object?

Comment: I am using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken and I have imported it as `jwt`

Comment: Surprisingly, now it works even though I did not change anything. Should I close the question?

Comment: well, I was just about to say, the logic in your code works fine on testing

Comment: Yeah. Closing, then! Thanks for your help.